# Arctangent integral representation of Catalan's constant

Tags: calculus

I've seen the Catalan's constant C (or G), which is defined by

$$C=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}$$

and $C \approx 0.915965594...$

Catalan's constant has a huge variety of integral representations. I actually can't prove any of them, but one that particularly interested me is this arctangent integral Wolfram|Alpha provided;

$$C=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x}dx$$

How would you prove this identity?

Answer (score 2):

With the Taylor expansion,
$$
\mathrm{Arctan}~x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}.
$$
Therefore, you can obtain
$$
C = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x~\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}x^{2n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)^{2}}.
$$